# How can I wrangle this csv into D3-ready json?

Tags: json, r

I'm working on building out a [stacked column chart](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch11.html#_stack_layout) and trying to figure out the cleanest way to transform my CSV data:

```
data <-   "apples oranges grapes
    5 10 22 
    4 12 28 
    2 19 32
    7 23 35
    23 17 43"
fruits <- read.table(text=data, header=TRUE)
```

into multi-dimensional JSON:

```
var dataset = [  
       //apples
        [
                { x: 0, y: 5 },
                { x: 1, y: 4 },
                { x: 2, y: 2 },
                { x: 3, y: 7 },
                { x: 4, y: 23 }
        ], //oranges
        [
                { x: 0, y: 10 },
                { x: 1, y: 12 },
                { x: 2, y: 19 },
                { x: 3, y: 23 },
                { x: 4, y: 17 }
        ], // grapes
        [
                { x: 0, y: 22 },
                { x: 1, y: 28 },
                { x: 2, y: 32 },
                { x: 3, y: 35 },
                { x: 4, y: 43 }
        ]
];
```

I can use `rson`'s `toJSON` to get a basic array:

```
{
 "apples":[5,4,2,7,23],
 "oranges":[10,12,19,23,17],
 "grapes":[22,28,32,35,43]
}
```

But I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how I'd transform that into the format that I actually need. I'm happy to make the transformation in JavaScript if that's more straightforward, though I'd like to figure out how to make it in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a `list` of `data.frame`s by `cbind`ing row sequence with each column of 'fruits' (using `Map`), set the names of the `list` with the column names of 'fruits', and use `toJSON` from `jsonlite`.

```
library(jsonlite)
toJSON(setNames(Map(function(x,y) data.frame(x,y),
            list(1:nrow(fruits)), fruits), names(fruits)))
{"apples":
 [
    {"x":1,"y":5},
    {"x":2,"y":4},
    {"x":3,"y":2},
    {"x":4,"y":7},
    {"x":5,"y":23}
],"oranges":
[
    {"x":1,"y":10},
    {"x":2,"y":12},
    {"x":3,"y":19},
    {"x":4,"y":23},
    {"x":5,"y":17}
],"grapes":
[
    {"x":1,"y":22},
    {"x":2,"y":28},
    {"x":3,"y":32},
    {"x":4,"y":35},
    {"x":5,"y":43}
]}
```